# Getting Empty JSON As Response From Spring Controller

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, serialization

In of my spring controllers I am returning response body like this `return new ResponseEntity(response, HttpStatus.OK);` But I am getting `{}` as response in postman. I have added a log line just before returning response and confirmed that I have a valid response body with members set to relevant values.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/v2/endpoint", method = {RequestMethod.POST}, produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<ResponseDto> getResponse(@Valid @RequestBody Request request,
                                                           @RequestHeader(name = "Accept-Language", defaultValue = "en") String locale,
                                                           @RequestHeader(name = "App-Version", required = false) Integer appVersion)  {
    try {
       
        ResponseDto responseDto = service.getResponse(request, locale, appVersion);
        log.info("responseDto : {}", responseDto);
        return new ResponseEntity(responseDto, HttpStatus.OK);
    }  catch (Exception ex) {
        log.error("Error ",  ex);
        throw  ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you paste your code snippet?

Comment: Can you try the following?

return ResponseEntity.ok().body(responseDto);

Comment: I have tried this. but no luck.

Comment: May I know what version of spring boot and jdk you're using? I tried it in Jdk 19 and spring boot 3.0.0 and worked fine.

Comment: I guess it's not an issue with the version. I have other controllers too and those are working fine. It might be related to serialization.

Comment: Please provide the definition of ResponseDto

Answer (score 0):

This is really weird.

For my response object `ResponseDto` I used lombok's `@Data` for getters and setters. But somehow during serialization those getters were not working and I really don't know why `(If someone knows, please let me know)`.

Then I replaced `@Data` annotation with traditional getters and it worked.

Comment: There could be many possibilities and its difficult to figure out with just controller class. Are fields of `ResponseDto` marked as `final` or annotated with `@NonNull`?

Comment: Fields were not marked as @NonNull or final.

Comment: and are you calling `ResponseDto` constructor somewhere?